# Output comes twice - Update of a Q asked 30 minutes before posting this one

Tags: python, list, indexing, append, range

Here is my code

```
import re
    with open('newfiles.txt') as f:
        k = f.read()
    p = re.compile(r'[\w\:\-\.\,\']+|[^[\w\:\-\.\'\,]\s]')
    originaltext = p.findall(k)
    uniquelist = []
    for word in originaltext:
        if word not in uniquelist:
            uniquelist.append(word)
    indexes = ' '.join(str(uniquelist.index(word)+1) for word in originaltext)
    n = p.findall(indexes)
    file = open("newfiletwo.txt","w")
    file.write (' '.join(str(e) for e in n))
    file.close()
    file = open("newfilethree.txt","w")
    file.write(' '.join(uniquelist))
    file.close()
    with open('newfiletwo.txt') as f:
        indexess = f.read()
    with open('newfilethree.txt') as f:
        differentwords = f.read()
    differentwords = p.findall(differentwords)
    indexess = [uniquelist.index(word) for word in originaltext] 
    for word in originaltext:
        if not word in differentwords:
            differentwords.append(word)
        i = differentwords.index(word)
        indexess.append(i)
    s = "" # the reconstructed sentence
    for i in indexess:
        s = s + differentwords[i] + " "
    print(s)
```

The program basically takes an external text file, returns the index of its positions (if any word repeats, then the first position is taken) and then saves the positions as an external file. Whilst doing this, I have split up the text file including splitting punctuation and saved different words and punctuation that occur in the file as an external file too. Now for the hard part, using both of these external files - the indexes and the different separated words, I am trying to recreate the original text file, including the punctuation. But the error shown in the title occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\Python\Index.py", line 31, in <module>
           s = s + differentwords[i] + " "
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not trying to sound rude but I am a sort of beginner, please try to change as less as possible in a simple way, as I have created this myself. You guys maybe know a far shorter way to do this, but this is the level of simplicity I can handle, proved by the length of the code. I have tried to shorten the original text file but that proves no use. Anyone know why the error occurs and how to fix it? I am not looking for efficiency right now, maybe after another couple of months of learning, but the simplest (i don't mind long) answer will be the best. Sorry if I have repeated myself a lot :-)

'newfiles' - A bunch of sentences with punctuation

UPDATE

The code does not show the error but prints the original sentence twice. The error has gone due to the removal of +1 on line 23. Does anyone know why the output repeats twice though?

Comment: This is suspect: `indexess = [uniquelist.index(word)+1 for word in originaltext]`. Why add one?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski WOW thx man, probably a bug as I thought python starts counting from zero, probably got confused and forgot to delete it. This has changed the result a lot, but the entire text file repeats twice, and there are spaces between the punctuation and the words, i guess from the result of splitting them from the words. Do you know how to fix the two issues?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski In case you wanted to know 'newfiles' is just a couple of sentences with punctuation - this has been edited into the question

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Nvm, thx for trying :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, how you qualify what word is, what is not. For instance is comma part of word? In your case that is not mentioned as such, while it is also not a separator. So you end up with separate word comma, or dot, and so on. I have no access to your input, so I can just provide sample:

`p = re.compile(r'[\w\:\-\.\,]+|[^[\w\:\-\.\,]\s]')`

There is one point - in this case: 'Word', 'word', 'Word', 'Word.', 'word,' are all separate words. Since dot, and coma are parts of word. You can't eat cake and have it. To fix that... you need to store information if there is white space before separation.

UPDATE:
Oh, yes. Double output. Files that are stored in the middle - are OK. So something was filed after that. Look at this two lines:

        `i = differentwords.index(word)
        indexess.append(i)`

They need to be inside preceding if statement.

Comment: Thx a lot, plus thank you for the explanation. But do you know any reason why the output repeats itself - it prints the same thing twice

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does really really help - been stuck on this for quite a while now :-)

Comment: Can i ask, what you are doing here by joining the regexes? Like what's the difference between this regex and the one already in my code? I tried afterwards to create one by myself, similar to this one but then my code doesn't work. Can you explain to me what this regex does?

Comment: For python there is nice tool - named kiki. On Ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install kiki`. Then you can provide sample code, regex, and visually test different options. Having it, please go to python docs for re module, and try different options. I've just found page - http://pythex.org/ - if that way is easier for anyone...

Comment: I know it's been a while but when you said "There is one point - in this case: 'Word', 'word', 'Word', 'Word.', 'word,' are all separate words. Since dot, and coma are parts of word. You can't eat cake and have it. To fix that... you need to store information if there is white space before separation.", How do I do it?

Comment: First you use dot, and comma as a part of word. I would treat it as a whitespace. Then we come to dash - sometimes that is simple- while space. But sometimes it is not. There are tools to deal with all of that - like nltk. But comparing to regex that is biggest cannon ever. :)

Comment: For upper-lower case you can lowercase string before processing. Problem here is that there are words - like names should be spelled in particular way... You can use source position, but then you can get word which has capital letter... Natural language is very problematic. :)